# How to filter audience in organic groups?

Tags: organic-groups, 7

I am using drupal commons. When i create an **organic group** I have the option of placing it within an existing group using the **audience** list. The audience list displays ALL groups (regardless if they are set to private). How can i make it so that the audience list only displays groups that belong to the creator (udid)?